# android values-v21 and values-ldrtl together

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to set `android:transitionName` for a view that has different properties for rtl or ltr direction.
In another words, I have 3 res folders: `values`, `values-ldrtl` and `values-v21`.
The question is how I set `android:transitionName` for a view in RTL direction?
Do I need a folder like named `values-v21-ldrtl`?
Here is some code:

**values:**

```
<style name="MyView" parent="ParentView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

**values-ldrtl:**

```
<style name="View" parent="MyView">
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
</style>
```

**values-ldrtl:**

```
<style name="View" parent="MyView">
    <item name="android:transitionName">@string/transition_name_test</item>
</style>
```

How do I combile `gravity` and `transitionName` in RTL layouts?
Thanks.

Comment: I think its values-ldrtl-v21 because the drawables are named drawable-ldrtl-hdpi

Comment: @Bhargav Thanks buddy. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use values-ldrtl-v21 folder instead of values-v21-ldrtl

Other way - create style for different versions and use it as parent for rtl/ltr